# Django social auth to update profile model

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using django-social-auth. Everything works fine except that profile model is not updated.
I have a OneToOneField with USER table. Whenver a user registers on site using e-mail, his profile is created automatically.
However when login with social credentials, profile is not automatically created.
What changes needs to be done for this to work. Thank you.

**Profile.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    contact_number= models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    official_email= models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    website= models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Urls:

```
url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
```

in settings

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/djsite'

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '234839666xxxxxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'c42dcdadf8902c4108b47c5de9xxxxxx'
FACEBOOK_EXTENDED_PERMISSIONS = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {'fields': 'email'}
```

Rest you can find on: 
[Bogotobogo](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Django/DjangoPython-Django-python-social-auth-facebook-twitter-google-auth.php)

Comment: Bogotobogo is a great resource -- so underrated!